# How can I check if a string contains only numbers, comma and periods with regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input field that I will only accept numbers, commas and periods. How can I test if the string is valid according to these rules?

**I have tried the following:**

```
var isValid = /([0-9][,][.])$/.test(str);
```

but it's not working. isValid variable is always false.

Comment: i don't but on keypress event we can restricted this symbols

Comment: I'm not familiar with javascript, but that regex says: one 0-9, followed by one "," and one ".", end of line.  You probably want /([0-9,.]+)$/.test(str);

Comment: wouldn't it be `/[\d,.]+/`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your regexp expects one character from the first class (0-9), then one from the second class (comma) then one from the last class (dot). Instead you want any number of characters (*) from the class containing digits, commas and dots (`[0-9,.]`). Also, you don't need the parenthesis:

```
var isValid = /^[0-9,.]*$/.test(str);
```

DEMO (and explanation): http://regex101.com/r/yK6oF4

Comment: Thanks, I will mark this an answer as soon as I can. Just a question. How do I add blank spaces to the allowed characters? would it be [0-9,. ]? (Notice the space after period)

Comment: @Weblurk Yes. You can use the tool i linked to try stuff out. The explanation of the regexp is most useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
var regex = "[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*"
```

This works perfect for decimal number & Integer.
e.g.

```
1 - true
1.1 - true
1.1.1 - false
1.a - false
```